# Need a C++ library to fit curves to data points

Tags: c++, regression, curve-fitting

I have a program that's creating data points, some of them are in the shape of a log function and some are lines. I need to be able to fit curves to these data points to be able to extrapolate. Are there any C++ libraries that can do this for me?

Answer (score 4):

Try the GNU scientific Library: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linear-regression.html

Answer (score 1):

CERN's ROOT package is probably your best option. It combines plotting, GUI resources, and stable computing resources together in one great package.